# Fatal error using python-javabridge JVM in Celery thread with NLTK on Mac OS X

Tags: python, celery, weka, java-bridge-method

I am using the [Python wrapper for Weka](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper) which is based on [python-javabridge](https://github.com/CellProfiler/python-javabridge). I have a long task to perform and, therefore, I am using [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to do so. The problem is I get

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff91a3c16f, pid=11698, tid=3587

JRE version:  (8.0_31-b13) (build )
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [libdispatch.dylib+0x616f]  _dispatch_async_f_slow+0x18b

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

when starting the JVM inside the thread. These two lines of code are used in order to do so (from [weka.core.jvm](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper/blob/master/python/weka/core/jvm.py#L116-L117)):

```
javabridge.start_vm(run_headless=True)
javabridge.attach()
```

From what I've read, it is probably caused by the fact that the JVM is not attached to the Celery thread. However, `javabridge.attach()` is indeed run inside it.

What am I missing ?

---

**EDIT:** I identified the code that is causing trouble. It has to do with an [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/index.html) tokenizer. The following code (according to [Vebjorn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769245/2086547)) will reproduce the error:

```
# hello.py
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
import javabridge
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('hello', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//', backend='amqp')

started = False    

@app.task
def hello():
    global started
    if not started:
        print 'Starting the VM'
        javabridge.start_vm(run_headless=True)
        started = True

    sentence = "This is a sentence with some numbers like 1, 2 or and some weird symbols like @, $ or ! :)"
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    tokenized_sentence = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence.lower())
    print "Tokens:", tokenized_sentence

    return javabridge.run_script('java.lang.String.format("Hello, %s!", greetee);',
                             dict(greetee='world'))
```

Without starting the JVM, the code runs properly. It also works when *not* running as a Celery task. I don't understand why it crashes.

---

**EDIT 2:** It actually works in a clean Ubuntu environment ([Dockerized](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerizing/)) but not on Mac OS X Yosemite (v10.3).

---

**EDIT 3:** As mentioned in the comments, it works if `from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer` is done inside the task wrapper, that is inside the `hello()` function.

Comment: Your modified example works for me, even in my Mac, if I move the NLTK import inside the task (i.e., inside the `hello` function).

Comment: Yes, it indeed works. Thanks for your first answer, it really helped to figure out how it worked and was actually the problem (or at least its origin). I however still don't understand why it doesn't work when the import is done outside the task wrapper and I would be really interested in the answer...someday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Celery starts four separate worker processes. (See the `-c` command line option to `celery worker`.) You need to ensure that you start the JVM in all of them. This example works for me:

```
# hello.py
import os
import threading
from celery import Celery
import javabridge

app = Celery('hello', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//', backend='amqp')

started = False

@app.task
def hello():
    global started
    if not started:
        print 'Starting the VM'
        javabridge.start_vm(run_headless=True)
        started = True
    return javabridge.run_script('java.lang.String.format("Hello, %s!", greetee);',
                                 dict(greetee='world'))
```

and

```
# client.py
from hello import hello

r = hello.delay()
print r.get(timeout=1)
```

1. Install on a virgin Ubuntu 14.04 machine:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update -y
   $ sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk python-pip python-numpy python-dev rabbitmq-server
   $ sudo pip install celery javabridge
   $ sudo /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start
   ```
2. Start worker:

   ```
   $ celery -A hello worker
   ...
    -------------- celery@a7cc1bedc40d v3.1.17 (Cipater)
   ---- **** ----- 
   --- * ***  * -- Linux-3.16.7-tinycore64-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
   -- * - **** --- 
   - ** ---------- [config]
   - ** ---------- .> app:         hello:0x7f5464766b50
   - ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
   - ** ---------- .> results:     amqp
   - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
   -- ******* ---- 
   --- ***** ----- [queues]
    -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


   [2015-04-21 10:04:31,262: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@a7cc1bedc40d ready.
   ```
3. In another window, run a client five times:

   ```
    $ python client.py 
    Hello, world!
    $ python client.py 
    Hello, world!
    $ python client.py 
    Hello, world!
    $ python client.py 
    Hello, world!
    $ python client.py 
    Hello, world!
   ```
4. Observe in the worker window that the JVM is started on the first four calls from the client (which go to four difference processes) but not in the fifth:

   ```
   [2015-04-21 10:05:53,491: WARNING/Worker-1] Starting the VM
   [2015-04-21 10:05:55,028: WARNING/Worker-2] Starting the VM
   [2015-04-21 10:05:56,411: WARNING/Worker-3] Starting the VM
   [2015-04-21 10:05:57,318: WARNING/Worker-4] Starting the VM
   ```

Comment: Thanks, Vebjorn. I could make your example work on my computer, but it doesn't work when I adapt my problematic code to it. Probably related to Weka then.